# InstagramのAPIでエラー・OAuthAccessTokenExceptionが発生する

Tags: python, api, instagram

現在以下の記事を参考に、Flaskを用いてinstagramユーザーの性別を推定しようと試みているのですが、instagramのAPIから引き受けたJSONデータを正しく取得できず、以下のようなエラーが発生してしまいます。 
http://codezine.jp/article/detail/8953

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
#一部省略
File "/Users/Ryosuke/fit_instagram_gender-codezine/main.py", line 21, in index
user_id = insta.user_id(user_name=user_name) # ユーザー名からユーザーIDを取得
File "/Users/Ryosuke/fit_instagram_gender-codezine/api.py", line 27, in user_id
for i in range(len(result["data"])):
KeyError: 'data'
```

print(result)をした結果、

```
{'error_message': 'The access_token provided is invalid.', 'code': 400, 'error_type': 'OAuthAccessTokenException'}
```

というエラーのJSONが出て来ました。 `api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=ユーザーID省略&access_token=省略`単体でリダイレクトし‌​た場合は正常なJSONデータが返ってくるのですが。

このような場合、どのようにしてJSONデータを正しく取得すればよいでしょうか?
是非ともご教示の程よろしくお願い致します。

以下に、JSONデータ、main.py、api.pyのコードを記載させて頂きます。

```
#"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=ユーザーID省略&access_token=省略"でリダイレクトした際のJSON
{"meta":{"code":200},"data":[{"username":"shinog_k","bio":"","website":"","profile_picture":"https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/t51.2885-19\/11429782_1619231825026977_59706782_a.jpg","full_name":"Ryosuke Kimura","id":"869626253"}]}
```

以下、api.pyとなります。

```
#api.py

from alchemyapi.alchemyapi import AlchemyAPI
import requests
# import requests_cache
import pandas as pd

# API呼び出しの結果をsqliteにキャッシュする
# requests_cache.install_cache('cache_instagram', allowable_methods=('GET', 'POST'))


# InstagramAPI
URL_ROOT = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/"

class InstagramAPI():
    def __init__(self, access_token):
        self.access_token = access_token

    def user_recent_media(self, user_id): # instagram最近の投稿画像の取得
        url = URL_ROOT + "users/{0}/media/recent/?access_token={1}".format(user_id, self.access_token)
        r = requests.get(url)
        return r.json()

    def user_id(self, user_name): # ユーザー名からユーザーIDの取得
        url = URL_ROOT + "users/search?q={0}&access_token={1}".format(user_name, self.access_token)
        r = requests.get(url)
        result = r.json()
        user_id = None
        for i in range(len(result["data"])):
            if user_name == result["data"][i]["username"]:
                user_id = result["data"][i]["id"]
                break

        return user_id
#以下、省略
```

以下、main.pyとなります。

```
#main.py
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from settings import instgram_access_token
from api import InstagramAPI
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.externals import joblib

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

        if request.method == 'POST': # POST応答
            if request.form['message'] == '': #例外処理：ユーザー名未入力時
                message = "Please input your Instagram User name in the box"
                return render_template('index.html', title="Your gender?", method=request.method, message=message)
            else:
                message = "Your Instagram data"
                insta = InstagramAPI(access_token=instgram_access_token)
                user_name = request.form['message'] # ユーザー名を変数に代入
                user_id = insta.user_id(user_name=user_name) # ユーザー名からユーザーIDを取得
                profile_image = insta.profile_image(user_id) # プロフィール画像を取得
                user = {'user_name': user_name, 'user_id': user_id, 'image': profile_image} # ユーザー情報をまとめる
                user_summary = insta.user_info(user=user)
                # 特徴量ベクトルの整理
                test = {'nail': 0, 'hair': 0, 'person': 0, 'sport': 0, 'food': 0, 'night': 0, 'coffee': 0,
                        'wedding': 0, 'cake': 0, 'beer': 0, 'dog': 0, 'animal': 0, 'tree': 0, 'blossom': 0,
                        'cat': 0, 'flower': 0, 'sky': 0, 'nature': 0, 'cherry': 0, "user_name": "test", "user_id": "test"}
                X = pd.DataFrame([user_summary, test]).fillna(0)
                X['animal'] = X['animal']+X['dog']+X['cat']
                X['cosme'] = X['hair']+X['nail']
                X['nature'] = X['nature']+X['sky']+X['flower']+X['tree']+X['blossom']+X['cherry']
                X = X[X['user_name'] == user_name]
                X = X[['person', 'sport', 'food', 'night', 'coffee', 'wedding', 'cake', 'beer', 'animal', 'nature', 'cosme']]
                user_vec = X.values.tolist()[0]

                model_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "clf/clf.pkl")
                clf = joblib.load(model_path) # 識別器の読み込み
                result = clf.predict(user_vec) # 性別推定

                return render_template('index.html', title="Your gender?", method=request.method, userinfo=user_summary, result=result, message=message)
        else: # GET応答
            return render_template('index.html', title="Your gender?", method=request.method)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(debug=True, port=port, host='IPアドレス省略')
```

Comment: まず、`print(result)`などのデバッグprintを入れてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！

print(result)をした結果、
{'error_message': 'The access_token provided is invalid.', 'code': 400, 'error_type': 'OAuthAccessTokenException'}
というエラーのJSONが出て来ました。

"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=ユーザーID省略&access_token=省略"単体でリダイレクトした場合は正常なJSONデータが返ってくるのですが(> <)汗

Comment: `print(url)`などのデバッグprintで正しいURLを指定できているか確認済みですか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます！print(url)をした結果、
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=shinog_k&access_token=None とのことでアクセストークンがNoneと表示がされ、正常に格納されていないようでした。

Comment: `main.py`の`instgram_access_token`が既におかしかったりはしないですか？

Comment: instgram_access_tokenに格納されている値自体には間違いはないと思われます。以下、setting.pyのコードになります。  

import os  

instgram_access_token = os.environ.get('省略')  
alchemyapi_key = os.environ.get("省略")

Comment: 「思う」だけではなくて、`print(instgram_access_token)`で確認していますか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り、'NoneType' object is not iterableとエラーが出てしまったことから、api.pyのinstgram_access_tokenがmain.pyに上手く格納できていないようです。

Comment: `print(instgram_access_token)`で`not iterable`と言われたのですか？ `instgram_access_token`は`setting.py`から`import`しているのでは無いのですか？ 構成が変わりましたか？ (追加情報の提供はコメントではなく、質問を編集して行なうほうがよいです)

Comment: 気のせいかも知れませんが、環境変数に関して何か勘違いなさっているかもしれませんね。上のコメントの`setting.py`についてですが、なぜ環境変数名を"省略"にしているのですか？ もしかしてアクセストークンなどを指定していますか？